# R markdown bookdown table caption issue

Tags: r, markdown, bookdown, kable, kableextra

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "test"
date: "2024-03-05"
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


this is the reference to Table \@ref(tab:test)
```{r test, echo=F, error=F, warning=F, message=F, results="asis", tidy=F}
require(gapminder)
require(tidyverse)
top_gap <- head(gapminder)


knitr::kable(top_gap,caption = "The first 6 rows of the dataset, gapminder")%>%
 kableExtra::kable_classic(full_width=F, html_font='Cambria', position="left")

```
````

provides two captions above table

[image]

I expected 1 table caption...It does not happen when I remove the kable_classic part. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `kableExtra::kbl` in place of `knitr::kable`.

Comment: Alternatively, specify the format, i.e. `knitr::kable(format="html", ...` .